# Combine two different sized array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two different sized arrays like this

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'One', contacts: [] }, 
 { id: 2, name: 'Two', contacts: [] }, 
 { id: 3, name: 'Three', contacts: [] }, 
 { id: 4, name: 'Four', contacts: [] }]

[{ id: 1, name: 'One', contacts: [{ id: 100, name: "C1" }, { id: 101, name: "C2" }] },
 { id: 3, name: 'Three', contacts: [{ id: 120, name: "C1" }, { id: 121, name: "C2" }] },
 { id: 5, name: 'Five', contacts: [{ id: 420, name: "F1" }, { id: 421, name: "F2" }] }];
```

**I tried with below code in javascript**

```
const mergeArray = (source, merge, by) => source.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    ...(merge.find(i => i[by] === item[by]) || {}),
    }));

    output =  mergeArray(this.oldArray1,this.oldArray2,'id');
```

**It gives output as**

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'One', contacts: [{ id: 100, name: "C1" }, { id: 101, name: "C2" }] }, 
{ id: 2, name: 'Two', contacts: [] }
{ id: 3, name: 'Three', contacts: [{ id: 120, name: "C1" }, { id: 121, name: "C2" }] }]
```

**But desired output like this**

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'One', contacts: [{ id: 100, name: "C1" }, { id: 101, name: "C2" }] }, 
{ id: 2, name: 'Two', contacts: [] }
{ id: 3, name: 'Three', contacts: [{ id: 120, name: "C1" }, { id: 121, name: "C2" }] },
{ id: 4, name: 'Four', contacts: [] }
{ id: 5, name: 'Five', contacts: [{ id: 420, name: "F1" }, { id: 421, name: "F2" }] }]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sorry: what is your problem: [SO] is not a code writing service. We'll help debug your code.

Comment: Ok, and what's your question? Before you say "how do I do this?" you should at least try yourself.

Comment: Loop your objects and do `$.extend({}, obj1.contacts, obj2.contacts)`

Comment: Hint: you can create a map from names to objects and merge the ones with same name.

Comment: **I tried** 

`const mergeArray = (source, merge, by) => source.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    ...(merge.find(i => i[by] === item[by]) || {}),
    }));

    this.mergedArray =  mergeArray(this.oldArray1,this.oldArray2,'id');`

**but getting output as**

`[{ id: 1, name: 'One', contacts: [{ id: 100, name: "C1" }, { id: 101, name: "C2" }] }, 
{ id: 2, name: 'Two', contacts: [] }
{ id: 3, name: 'Three', contacts: [{ id: 120, name: "C1" }, { id: 121, name: "C2" }] }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could collect the arrays in an array, or simply concat the arrays and then reduce this array by checkin if the `id` is in the result array. If not add the object to the result array or if exist, then extend `contacts` with the acutal data.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'One', contacts: [] }, { id: 2, name: 'Two', contacts: [] }, { id: 3, name: 'Three', contacts: [] }, { id: 4, name: 'Four', contacts: [] }],
    array2 = [{ id: 1, name: 'One', contacts: [{ id: 100, name: "C1" }, { id: 101, name: "C2" }] }, { id: 3, name: 'Three', contacts: [{ id: 120, name: "C1" }, { id: 121, name: "C2" }] }, { id: 5, name: 'Five', contacts: [{ id: 420, name: "F1" }, { id: 421, name: "F2" }] }],
    merged = [array1, array2].reduce((r, a) => {
        a.forEach(o => {
            var object = r.find(({ id }) => id === o.id);
            if (!object) {
                return r.push(o);
            }
            object.contacts.push(...o.contacts);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```